# MANOVA with SciPy

Tags: python, manova, scipy

Is it possible to conduct a multivariate ANOVA with Python and SciPy?
I would prefer to stick to the SciPy stack (NumPy, Statsmodels, Scikit-Learn, Matplotlib, etc.)

Comment: MANOVA is in statsmodels master and will be in the next release in Fall. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/3291

Comment: Now it is possible! from 2018-05-15.  
http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/release/version0.9.html

[MANOVA  documentaion](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.multivariate.manova.MANOVA.html)